# Cordova not reflecting changes in js files

Tags: javascript, cordova, webpack

I am doing school project and we have to use Cordova. I created Cordova app and I set up Webpack. Site showed "Hello webpack", so everything worked fine.

Then I installed React and changed main.js file, but my site is still showing "Hello webpack" even when it is not in the file anymore.

During the changes I used this command:

```
chokidar "**/*.js" "www/**" -c "cordova prepare browser"
```

I could see this in the terminal:

> Watching "**/*.js", "www/**" .. change:src/main.js

I also tried manually `cordova preapre` and then `cordova run browser`, but nothing changed.

I can see changes in www/index.html file. Just not the js files.

**edit**
I was probably using wrong command. Now I use this one and everything works:

```
chokidar "www/**" -c "cordova run browser"
```

Answer (score 0):

please take a [look at](https://github.com/sombriks/cordova-react-issue) [these](https://github.com/sombriks/sample-cordova-vue) [repositories](https://github.com/sombriks/react-browserify-firebase). Those setups differs from yours but might help building one for your project.